# Limits of a sequence solved as limits of continuous function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, taylor-expansion, sequence-of-function

I was trying to solve the following (pointwise) limit:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x)=\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} n(x^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-x)$$
Where $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence of functions defined as $f_n(x)=n(x^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-x)$.
And the only thing that came up in my mind was to solve it in the following way:
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow +\infty} n(x^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-x)=\lim _{n \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{x^{n+1}-x}{n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{nx\log x+o(n)}{n}=x\log x$$
Using the Maclaurin series for $g(n)=x^{n+1}-x$. Now my doubt is: considering that the Maclaurin series exist for a continuous (and perhaps differentiable several times) function, and a sequence isn't a continuous function, is it legit what I've done? More generally, can we use methods for continuous functions even for the sequences (in case the sequence is "naturally extendible" to a continuous function, like $g(n))$? If the answer is yes, why can we do this? And how can we solve this limit without using methods for continuous functions (Taylor series, De l'Hopital, and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

For fix $x>0$ let $g(t):=x^{1+t}.$

Then

$$n(x^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-x)=\frac{g(\frac{1}{n})-g(0)}{\frac{1}{n}} \to g'(0)$$

as $n \to \infty.$